# Why do twemoji fails with most of emoji unicodes?

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji

I am using the library [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) in my project.

Now, the examples in GitHub work fine on my local computer, but if I try this:
`twemoji.parse('\u1f600')` I get a weird result: `ὠ0`.

It seems to me that this library works fine for `4` digits unicodes but fails with `5` digits unicodes.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMA-script uses 16 bit unicode (UTF16), so `'\u1f600'` indeed parses as `ὠ0`. twemoji has a conversion utility `convert.fromCodePoint(STRING)`. You might give it a try with `convert.fromCodePoint('1f600')` (no leading `\u`!).

Comment: Cool. Thank you so much!